# Как правильно расставить элементы горизонтальное меню?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: вид меню]

даное меню я сделал через flex;
Но проблема в том,что очень плохо двигаються пункты меню.
Как правельно их двигать.И может кто знает другой способ создания такого меню не через flex(с расстановкой-а не все по-ЦЕНТРУ!вместе!)
спасибо )

Comment: Можно через `float`'ы, можно через `position: absolute`. По описанию и без кода неясно, в чем именно проблема.

Comment: вопрос в том,как еще можна создать такое меню,что б была возможность так расставить пункты.?!!!

Comment: Так а с `float` совсем ничего у вас не получилось? Вам нужно готовое решение или подсказка, как сделать?

Comment: если можна то готовое решение,что б посмотреть.
Просто мне не очень нравиться то как я сделал через flex,хотел б посмотреть другой вариант.

Comment: Простейший вариант без заморочек https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/0zkct8qd/

Comment: оно там вообще не по-средине))))

Comment: Что не посредине чего?

Comment: ну текст не по-средине(вертикально) поля

Comment: У вас на изображении то, как должно быть, или то, как у вас получилось?

Comment: я уже сделал через line-height)
Вроде получилось)

Comment: А, вы забыли указать, что вам нужно вертикальное выравнивание.